# Pythonを使用して、BluetoothのRSSI値を取得したい。

Tags: python, iphone, bluetooth

Raspberry Pi 2を使って、スマートフォン端末のRSSI値をPythonで取得する方法が分かりません。よい方法があればお教え頂けませんでしょうか？

下記のコードは、Bluetoothを利用してユーザの入退室の時間を記録するものです。
このコードに、複数のスマートフォン端末がBluetoothの通信範囲に入っている場合、RSSI値が最も高い端末に条件分岐する機能を追加したいです。

環境はPython2.7.9、PyBluez0.2.2を使用しています。

```
import bluetooth
import time

print "In/Out Board"

while True:
    print "Checking " + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())

    result = bluetooth.lookup_name('00:00:00:00:00:00', timeout=5) 
    if (result != None):
        print "John: in"
    else:
        print "John: out"

    result = bluetooth.lookup_name('00:00:00:00:00:00', timeout=5)
    if (result != None):
        print "Paul: in"
    else:
        print "Paul: out"

    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/57817

Answer (score 1):

```
bluetooth.byte_to_signed_int()
```

で取得できるようです。

[こちら](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/advanced/inquiry-with-rssi.py)の下記のコードを参考にしてみてはいかがでしょうか

```
def device_inquiry_with_with_rssi(sock):
    # save current filter
    old_filter = sock.getsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, 14)

    # perform a device inquiry on bluetooth device #0
    # The inquiry should last 8 * 1.28 = 10.24 seconds
    # before the inquiry is performed, bluez should flush its cache of
    # previously discovered devices
    flt = bluez.hci_filter_new()
    bluez.hci_filter_all_events(flt)
    bluez.hci_filter_set_ptype(flt, bluez.HCI_EVENT_PKT)
    sock.setsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, flt )

    duration = 4
    max_responses = 255
    cmd_pkt = struct.pack("BBBBB", 0x33, 0x8b, 0x9e, duration, max_responses)
    bluez.hci_send_cmd(sock, bluez.OGF_LINK_CTL, bluez.OCF_INQUIRY, cmd_pkt)

    results = []

    done = False
    while not done:
        pkt = sock.recv(255)
        ptype, event, plen = struct.unpack("BBB", pkt[:3])
        if event == bluez.EVT_INQUIRY_RESULT_WITH_RSSI:
            pkt = pkt[3:]
            nrsp = bluetooth.get_byte(pkt[0])
            for i in range(nrsp):
                addr = bluez.ba2str( pkt[1+6*i:1+6*i+6] )
                rssi = bluetooth.byte_to_signed_int(
                        bluetooth.get_byte(pkt[1+13*nrsp+i]))
                results.append( ( addr, rssi ) )
                print("[%s] RSSI: [%d]" % (addr, rssi))
        elif event == bluez.EVT_INQUIRY_COMPLETE:
            done = True
        elif event == bluez.EVT_CMD_STATUS:
            status, ncmd, opcode = struct.unpack("BBH", pkt[3:7])
            if status != 0:
                print("uh oh...")
                printpacket(pkt[3:7])
                done = True
        elif event == bluez.EVT_INQUIRY_RESULT:
            pkt = pkt[3:]
            nrsp = bluetooth.get_byte(pkt[0])
            for i in range(nrsp):
                addr = bluez.ba2str( pkt[1+6*i:1+6*i+6] )
                results.append( ( addr, -1 ) )
                print("[%s] (no RRSI)" % addr)
        else:
            print("unrecognized packet type 0x%02x" % ptype)
        print("event ", event)


    # restore old filter
    sock.setsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, old_filter )

    return results
```